# Trim float values upto 4 decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where it needs to display 4 values up to 4 decimal places. while using the round function it doesn't round up. Below are some of the functions that i have tried. But couldn't get it to work. Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

```
    SELECT  CAST(0.1173 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    INTO #TEMP
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(12.1373 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.7065 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.7065 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.3534 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.4534 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.5732 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.6487 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound   

    select DontRound,Round(DontRound,4,1)  
   , CAST(left(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DontRound,128),   charindex('.',CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DontRound,128)) + 4) AS FLOAT) 
from #temp
```

I would like to see the output in float datatype, if that is possible.

Thanks

Comment: All your numbers have 4 digit precision and you are trying to round them to 4 digit. So no rounding happens as your numbers already have 4 precision.

Comment: If you try it with different examples you might be able to see the difference. Couldnt include all the scenarios. sorry

Comment: for the above query, what is the desired result? If you edit your question and add the expected result, it will help us to answer the question.

Comment: I'm doing lot of calculations in my query, and i would like to see the results without any rounding up 4 decimal places. When I'm trying to use ROUND Function it doesn't work. For example, while using round(ColumnData,4,1). The value 1.151785 is getting converted to 1.1518 in my database. So wanted to see if there is a way to get the same data as 1.1517

Comment: Round of 1.151785 is 1.1518 not 1.1517. So you are going to cut the extra digits, right?

Comment: yes, that is correct!!!

Comment: If you are just _displaying_ data rounded (or truncated) to 4 digits that do that in the display layer (app, report, web site, whatever). Otherwise any further calculations will also be using rounded data which may accentuate any rounding error.  It's not clear exactly what your requirements are but rounding data in SQL just to change how it's displayed can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula you need to use:

```
declare @num float = 21.151785
select cast(floor(@num) as varchar(100)) + 
    substring(cast(@num - floor(@num) as varchar(100))
              , charindex('.', cast(@num - floor(@num) as varchar(100)), 1)
              , 5)
```

Result will be `21.1517`

Note that, in case the precision is less than 4 `(like 1.151)`, you may want to add trailing Zero to the result.

**Test:**

```
SELECT  CAST(0.11735 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
INTO #TEMP
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(12.13738 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(0.70651 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(0.70656 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(0.35342 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(0.45347 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(0.5732 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(11.05 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(126.2158 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(0.6487 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
```

Query

```
select DontRound,
cast(floor(DontRound) as varchar(100)) + 
    substring(cast(DontRound - floor(DontRound) as varchar(100))
              , charindex('.', cast(DontRound - floor(DontRound) as varchar(100)), 1) 
              , 5) AS CutDecimal
from #TEMP
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ DontRound ║ CutDecimal ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║   0.11735 ║     0.1173 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║  12.13738 ║    12.1373 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║   0.70651 ║     0.7065 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║   0.70656 ║     0.7065 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║   0.35342 ║     0.3534 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║   0.45347 ║     0.4534 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║    0.5732 ║     0.5732 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║     11.05 ║      11.05 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║  126.2158 ║   126.2158 ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║    0.6487 ║     0.6487 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: For most part it is working but in some instances like 126.2158 is returning 126.2157 in my database.

Comment: Also for 11.05 its returning 11.0499

Comment: It returns 126.2158 are you sure?

Comment: just put your numbers in first line of my query. if you see a different result when you select from table, it might be something else

Comment: Yes, That's what it is returning by my database by not using the declare statements though. Weird!!!

Comment: It works while using the declare statement but not using it in a select statement.

Comment: I think in case of 11.05, the actual number you have in database is 11.0499, if you see 11.05, it is rounded, how do you see your actual field?,

Comment: I'm inserting the values in a #temp table and the column datatype is float. The actual number in the #temp table is 11.05. When using ur function it gives 11.0499. Also for 11 its rounding it to 110.

Comment: I added test data and the result. It looks good. I have no idea why you get a different result!!

Comment: The result is a VARCHAR string not a float or numeric data type it will take an additional CAST.  But if you leave this operation mathematical it is far simplier.  FLOOR(DontRound * 10000)/10000

Answer (score 1):

```
FLOOR(DontRound * 10000)/10000
```

Keep it numeric operation.  times it by 10,000 because you are looking for the ten thousand th (.0000) then take the floor essentially rounds down to nearest whole integer dropping off remaining decimals then divide it by 10,000 again to convert back to the decimal value you want.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  CAST(0.1173 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(12.1373 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.7065 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.7065 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.3534 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.4534 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.5732 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(0.6487 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(1.151785 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(126.2158 AS FLOAT) AS DontRound
)

SELECT *, FLOOR(DontRound * 10000)/10000
FROm
    cte
```

Also note float isn't as precise as other data types for calculations.  you may want to do some research on that depending on your application/use.

Comment: Hey this is much better solution! why did you mark my post as answer? My mistake was, I limited my thoughts around your initial query. Good lesson for me :)

Comment: Thanks @FLICKER, I am not too worried about the marking I think you got him where he needed to get first and your solution worked. so I commend you on it!  Glad this will help in the future. cheers